# Installing R on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, package-management, r

I had `R 3.3.0` on my machine. During the process of upgrading `R`, I had some problems. Now I'm getting the following error when I try to install `R`.

```
yaseen@yaseen:~$ sudo apt-get install r-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.3.0-2xenial0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 3.3.0-2xenial0) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any help to overcome this issue will be highly appreciated. Thanks

**Edited**

I tried

```
sudo apt-get remove r-base && sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get remove r-base && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: How did you originally install 3.3.0 and how did you attempt to upgrade it? What is the output of `apt-cache policy r-base`